# Postgresql update 2 tables in one update statement

Tags: postgresql, sql-update, multi-query

I have two different tabs with same field, like:

```
host.enabled, service.enabled.
```

How I can update his from 1 update statement?

I tried:

```
UPDATE hosts AS h, services AS s SET h.enabled=0, s.enabled=0
    WHERE
    ctid IN (
    SELECT hst.ctid FROM hosts hst LEFT JOIN services srv ON hst.host_id = srv.host_id
        WHERE hst.instance_id=1
    );
```

On mysql syntax this query worked like this:

```
UPDATE hosts LEFT JOIN services ON hosts.host_id=services.host_id SET hosts.enabled=0, services.enabled=0 WHERE hosts.instance_id=1
```

Comment: That won't work. Is your goal to ensure that both updates are done, or none if something goes wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I didn't really understand your schema.  If you can set up a fiddle that would be great.

In general though to update two tables in a single query the options are:

[**Trigger**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createtrigger.html)

This makes the assumption that you always want to update both together.

[**Stored procedure/function**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createfunction.html)

So you'll be doing it as multiple queries in the function, but it can be triggered by a single SQL statement from the client.

[**Postgres CTE extension**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/queries-with.html)

Postgres permits common table expressions (with clauses) to utilise data manipulation.

```
with changed_hosts as (
  update hosts set enabled = true 
  where host_id = 2 
  returning * 
)
update services set enabled = true 
where host_id in (select host_id from changed_hosts);
```

In this case the update in the WITH statement runs and sets the flag on the hosts table, then the main update runs, which updates the records in the services table.

SQL Fiddle for this at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/fa4d3/1

In general though, its probably easiest and most readable just to do 2 updates wrapped in a transaction.

Comment: I have mysql query:

UPDATE hosts LEFT JOIN services ON hosts.host_id=services.host_id SET hosts.enabled=0, services.enabled=0 WHERE hosts.instance_id=1

this query work fine on mysql, but postgresql dont understand left join in this position.

Comment: That's why I didn't include a mysql answer to your postgresql question.

Comment: Thanks, i'm used transaction.

Comment: The question was about a solution with one statement. The response should say "No. It's not possible" and then gives alternatives

Comment: @apflieger except that it is possible, which is why I included the CTE in there.